# Is it appropriate to copy paste questions from Christianity.SE?

Tags: discussion

I've been really impressed with the quality of answers given on Hermeneutics.SE, and was wondering:

Is it acceptable for me to copy and paste my questions from Christianity.SE that I think would  be fitting here?

Comment: Just checking Eric, you know how voting works a little differently on meta right?

Comment: @Caleb, no - I haven't spent much time on meta before now.  What's the difference?

Comment: Glad I checked then. I always try to catch lower rep folks when they first show up on meta. Because meta is usually frequented by experienced users, we sometimes forget that people don't always know the ropes.

Comment: On main sites voting is supposed to be some indication of quality/usefulness. Upvotes mean a question is useful, well researched and clearly focused. Downvotes would indicate maybe you have a problem in some area. **On meta it's all different.** Voting tends to indicate agreement or disagreement on an issue. Your question here was not only valid, it is appreciated that you took the time to ask because it's a constructive way to pursue a quality community. I'm sure the downvote here is indicative of somebody that thinks copy-paste shouldn't happen, not that this was a bad question to ask!

Comment: Oh, got it.  Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, no straight up copying is a bad idea.

If you see a good question that can be tweaked to target the specifically different set of expertise that the non doctrinal focus here provides, then by all means ask it. If the question is really Christian in nature and it just isn't getting attention, let's look at other options such as trying to get cross over experts, adding a bounty over there, or migrating here add appropriate.

While there is and always will be some scope overlap between the sites, I would like to discourage dilution of experts that would happen by just throwing topics out there twice. If we knowingly approach both communities with a question, let's tailor it to the strengths of each.

Comment: I agree completely.

Comment: Thanks - the questions I had in mind were asked on Christianity.SE, but probably mistakenly, because they were meant to be about doctrinal implications of passages (which seems to be on topic here: [To what extent are "Christian doctrine" questions off topic?](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/308) rather than Christian doctrines themselves.  If I decide to ask them here, I'll reword them as appropriate.

Comment: @Eric: [Is the highway mentioned in Isaiah a literal highway?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/5660/914) could probably migrated as is.  I _might_ get around to answering [What do 1st century extra-biblical sources say about hell?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/6866/914) but it ought to stay on C.SE.  [Why was Hebrews included in the canon?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/6557/914) could be migrated with a few changes.  Otherwise, I encourage you to rephrase the questions to focus on the meaning of the _text_ if you want to ask here.  (They will be welcome.)

Comment: Thanks @JonEricson, I appreciate the specificity.

Answer (score 4):

### No

I'll start with the general opinion that cross-posting is generally discouraged.  In a sense, Christianity.SE (and to a less extent, Judaism.SE) are occupying similar niches and we don't want to confuse things by having identical questions with different answers.  If you have a question on another StackExchange site and you think it hasn't gotten the sort of answers you are hoping for *and* you think it would be better served on Biblical Hermeneutics, then you should flag it for a moderator to migrate.

### Maybe

If you *did* get a satisfactory answer on Christianity.SE, especially if it's explicitly Christian, and you think you can get a different answer here, then you could ask here too.  But please *don't* just copy-and-paste and *do* include a link to the original question.  As an example of the "same" question on both sites, I saw a [question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/4670/914) on where in the Bible it says we should celebrate Christian holidays, and [rephrased](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/653/68) it to ask whether Paul rejected celebrating holidays in Galatians.  I think the internet is richer for having these separate questions that tackle the same subject in different ways.